# mysql select into csv escape newline error

Tags: mysql, select, newline, file-io

I am trying to save a sql select into a csv file than I will later on open in excel

The error :

```
ERROR 1083 (42000) at line 1: Field separator argument is not what is expected; check the manual
```

And the query is:

```
SELECT 'Description' 
union
SELECT coalesce(replace(d.description,'\r\n','\n'),'') 
INTO OUTFILE \"$FILE_PATH$FILE_NAME\"
FIELDS ESCAPED BY '""' TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
FROM data d
```

The problem is with the "ESCAPED BY" is that it should escape new line characters saved in the database in the description field. (I don't want new characters in a file to create more than one line in excel when opening the csv).

Mysql server is version 5.5 . With 5.0 works fine but since the "ESCAPED BY" are used in the mysql tutorial i don't understand why i am getting problems here.

Source used for keeping newlines within the fields:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the ESCAPED BY clause is expecting a single character. Per the MySQL manual, the syntax is as follows:

```
[FIELDS
    [TERMINATED BY 'string']
    [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
    [ESCAPED BY 'char']
]
```

Changing ESCAPED BY '""' to ESCAPED BY '"' should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Idiot of me... Used the two double quotes in a previous version of mysql server and it worked, did not think on that. Cheers.